# How to handle 'API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory' in code (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, memory-leaks, signals

Below is a toy program I am using to throw process out of memory exception.

```
function alloc (size) {
    const numbers = size / 8;
    const arr = []
    arr.length = numbers; // Simulate allocation of 'size' bytes.
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    return arr;
};

const allocations = []; 

function allocToMax () {

    console.log("Start");

    const field = 'heapUsed';
    const mu = process.memoryUsage();
    console.log(mu);
    const gbStart = mu[field] / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
    console.log(`Start ${Math.round(gbStart * 100) / 100} GB`);

    let allocationStep = 100 * 1024;

    while (true) {

        const allocation = alloc(allocationStep);

        allocations.push(allocation);

        const mu = process.memoryUsage();
        const mbNow = mu[field] / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
        console.log(`Total allocated       ${Math.round(mbNow * 100) / 100} GB`);
        console.log(`Allocated since start ${Math.round((mbNow - gbStart) * 100) / 100} GB`);
    }
};

process.on('exit','SIGINT','', function() {
    console.log("tata");
});

allocToMax();
```

I am running the program with an upper memory limit of 4 mb like this node --max-old-space-size="4" index.js`.
As expected, the program will eventually go out of memory throwing exception like below

```
*#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#*
or 
*FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**
I am trying to detect the SIGNAL or anything else in code the process emits in case of Memory leak or FATAL ERROR so that I can perform a graceful exit and restart the server.
```

Mostly I need a handler, when process goes or is about to go out of memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pm2-runtime the server gets automatically restarts, without killing the docker.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/